# React - can't access environment variables in the server side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, environment-variables, create-react-app

I have created an app using Create-React-App on the client side and using express in the server side.  I have created an `.env` file for my environment variables where the `DB_USER` and `DB_PASSWORD` will be stored.

In the server side, I would like to use a mongoose connection and the `.env` variables will be the credentials when connecting to the mongodb server.

I'm getting undefined variables in the terminal console when I do `process.env.DB_USER`. Instead I'm getting my OS environment variables, and NodeJS variables.  However, I do see the variables when I do `console.log(process.env.DB_USER)` in chrome console/client side.

I tried to install `dotenv`, `dotenv-webpack` and configure my `webpack.config` but nothing seem to be working.  I have also added `REACT_APP_*` as prefix to my variables, but still undefined values.

Also when I use `dotenv` and set this `require('dotenv').config()` in my `index.js` file, it complains about an `fs` dependency??

I just can't get the environment variables to be read in the server folder, ideally it will be nice to have these variables read in the client and server folder.  Has anyone encountered this issue before?  I'm just learning how to use `Create-React-App` and `webpack`.  Your help will be appreciated!!!

server.js

```
//server.js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const router = require('./routes/routes.js')
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const user = process.env.REACT_APP_DBUSER;
const password = process.env.REACT_APP_DBPASSWORD;

//tells express frontend will reside in client folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

console.log('node', process.env);
console.log(user);//this is undefined

//connect to mongoDB
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${user}:${password}@ds141812.mlab.com:41812/note_app_db`, { useNewUrlParser: true });

let conn = mongoose.connection;
conn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection:'));
conn.once('open', () => {
    console.log('connected to database');
});

//pass in routes from router const
app.use('/',router)

module.exports=app;
```

webpack.config

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

const config = {
    entry: __dirname + '/client/js/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/react']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|gif|mp4|mov)$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '/assets/[name]-[hash:8].[ext]'
                }
            }]
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
        }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        publicPath: '/',
        contentBase: __dirname + '/build',
        port: 5000,
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: 'index.html'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: './client/index.html', to: './index.html' }
        ]),
        new Dotenv({
            path: './.env',
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development"),
                REACT_APP_DBUSER: JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_DBUSER),
                REACT_APP_DBPASSWORD: JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_DBPASSWORD)
            }
        })
    ]
}


module.exports = config
```

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
require('dotenv').config({path: '../../.env'});//is this how it supposed to look like???

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "note_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.5.7",
    "env-cmd": "^8.0.2",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.11",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.6",
    "react": "^16.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "webpack": "webpack --mode development",
    "dev": "npm run webpack && nodemon bin/www"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

.env file

```
REACT_APP_DBUSER="username"
REACT_APP_DBPASSWORD="password"
```

file structure
[image]

Comment: I’m client console can u see the values of DB credentials? If so there is something wrong and not good security wise

Comment: Hi medev21, did you mange to figure this issue out? I have the same problem.

Comment: @danielblythe I posted the solution below, what worked for me but here what I wrote:  "Found the solution, so dotenv is fine and I had uninstall dotenv-webpack. In order for the server.js file to read the environment variables, I just needed to add require('dotenv').config(); in this file. It should be good to go!"

Comment: Thanks medev21 but I've since realised that the frontend shouldn't have access to the server env variables because (for anyone reading this) the secrets/keys would be baked into the code and becoming a security risk. So I need to make requests from the front-end to the back end where the keys live to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution, so `dotenv` is fine and I had uninstall `dotenv-webpack`.  In order for the `server.js` file to read the environment variables,  I just needed to add `require('dotenv').config();` in this file.  It should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Replacing my old incorrect answer.

Rather than using that dotenv-webpack package, could you use this package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

In theory, you can remove that `new DotEnv` from your plugins and then when you call `require('dotenv').config()`, your webpack.config.js should have access to those env variables, then your webpack define plugin will pick them up and inject them into your code

Comment: I have already added the `REACT_APP_` to my variables and still the same issue.

Comment: I removed `new DotEnv` and still issue.  First I had an issue with the `fs` dependency so I had to add `node: {fs: 'empty'}` in `webpack.config.js`, it ran but still undefined values.  Then I added the path in the `dotenv`, so `require('dotenv').config({path: '../../.env'});` but still undefined values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install any package just write `REACT_APP` before your token then you can **process.env.REACT_APP_TOKEN_NAME**

### .env file looks like this

REACT_APP_TOKEN_NAME = fhsahffdsaf-sdfsf-fds